# Having my first supervision soon, but I have nothing to tell or even ask

Tags: research-process, graduate-school, advisor, supervision

I have my first supervision soon, but I don't really know what to talk about. I am working on a particular problem in the Humanities; my supervisor has given me a reading list, and well, I am currently working through it. I haven't come up with any novel ideas so far, but I also cannot think of any questions to ask her. I have not encountered any problems, but I am also not far enough to have anything written, or a table of contents ready.

What shall I do? What does my supervisor expect from me now? Obviously you won't know, but maybe you can *guess*? I am quite worried.

Comment: I'm not sure how it works in humanities, but this sounds like every grad student's early meetings with their advisor.  I felt like this most of the way through my Mathematics Ph.D., in any case.

Comment: thank you. I also have the feeling that, in general, I find it quite difficult to speak about my topic for one hour. I feel that I know mostly what needs to be done, or what my next steps should be. It's great that I can send an email if I get stuck, but right now I feel a bit overwhelmed. Feedback is of course helpful, but will be *most* helpful for work already written, which I can then revise. hm.

Comment: @JoMcBride unless your supervisions are very unlike mine, you're not giving a 1-hr presentation - you're having a conversation. Your supervisor is unlikely to expect you to stand in front of them for an hour and declaim :-) Feeling overwhelmed is also pretty common in the early (and later...) stages - if possible, try to build a relationship with your supervisor such that you can tell them that.

Answer (score 15):

I would guess that your supervisor simply wants to stay in touch, in general. I am in mathematics, but/and in early stages and even during their thesis-writing, my students often have said that they have no coherent questions, nothing to show, etc. In recent years I've attempted to more forcefully make the point that our weekly meetings are not at all necessarily about "good questions" (in math, the usual joke is that to be able to ask a good question is often more difficult than proving a good theorem...) nor about "progress". Rather, it's to stay in touch, chat about the project and related matters. Often, by-the-way questions come to light, often disclaimed as "dumb", but *these* are really the only questions anyone every has, and mostly I can answer them.

In a subtler way, "chatting" about things related to your project, or even only very distantly related, helps your advisor get to know you in that context. Very-experienced people can make a lot of high-likelihood inferences from details of casual technical conversation.

Also, there's the pep-talk aspect. Assuming things are going even approximately alright, your advisor has that opportunity to encourage you, or reassure you, etc. For that matter, especially later, it may become rather difficult for you to see whether you're making good progress, or not. After all, you've not written sooooo many theses? In contrast, presumably your advisor *has* seen many examples, and can reassure you that, yes, everything really does take this long, even when one works very hard.

Comment: Also there are people who are very afraid to ask "dumb" questions or ashamed that they don't progress as fast as they wish/think they should. If there is a regular meeting, asking this questions/talking about that has a lower barrier than sending an email or calling.

Comment: Sometimes, being able to ask the right question in the field makes for 30-40% of the work for a paper.

Answer (score 1):

You are going to be doing a lot of reading. Keeping track of what you read where, so that you can go back to interesting points later, is not trivial.

That gives you a useful topic to discuss. How are you managing your notes on the material you are reading? Can the supervisor suggest better ways of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

Unless your supervisor is a jerk (possible, but a minority), *they want to see you succeed*. If you have come straight from school and undergrad, you need to transition from thinking of your supervisor as a schoolteacher whose job it is to rank you and grade you at every opportunity, and start to see them as a supporter who is there to help and to make sure that you achieve something. That doesn't mean they won't be demanding, of course, and it doesn't lesson your responsibility for your own work, but it hopefully means you can be honest with them about progress. There's a good chance that they're not expecting any stunning insight at this stage!

In terms of specifics, you say you haven't had any ideas for research, but was there anything in what you've read so far that you found particularly interesting? If the meeting turns into awkward silence (hopefully unlikely), perhaps you can talk about that?